# MySQL: Does the order of the ON condition of a LEFT JOIN matter?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, **employees** and **unionMembers**. The people in **unionMembers** are a small subset of the people in **employees**. I want to do a SELECT query using a LEFT JOIN like so:

```
SELECT    wage, unionDues
FROM      employees 
LEFT JOIN unionMembers ON employees.ID = unionMembers.ID 
WHERE     employees.ID = 'ID001';
```

Does it matter if I do `ON employees.ID = unionMembers.ID` or reverse the order and do `ON unionMembers.ID = employees.ID`?

Let's say I have 100 employees and 5 of them are union members. When doing the LEFT JOIN, ideally it would have to do 5 comparisons instead of a 100. Would the order of the equality test make any difference?

Comment: I don't believe the order should matter but I don't have a MySQL database handy to prove that. What I think you could do, however, is run `EXPLAIN SELECT` for both options and compare the resulting query plans. If the plans end up being completely identical, the answer should be obvious. Feel free to post your own answer if you manage to reach a conclusion.

Comment: *Does it matter* No. Only the result makes sense.

Comment: When writing a `JOIN`, always qualify the column names.  In this example, if `unionDues` is in `unionMembers`, then the `IN (SELECT ...)` approach won't work.  If it is in `employees`, then why have the `LEFT JOIN` at all??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language; that is, it does not specify how something should be done, only what the result should be.

The computing languages I have used all respect the properties of equality, so `employees.ID = unionMembers.ID` is equivalent to `unionMembers.ID = employees.ID`

In this case, rather than an outer join, which can generate a large data-set, you would probably want to use a sub-query or the EXISTS operator, depending on your data structure. Something like:

`SELECT   ID,
          wage, 
          unionDues
FROM      employees 
WHERE     ID in (
    SELECT    ID
    FROM      unionMembers
    WHERE     ID = 'ID001'
    );`

There is an in-depth discussion here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

HTH